# Как изменить ответ на значение JSON в PHP массиве?

Tags: php, json

Как изменить ответ на значение JSON в PHP массиве?, нужно 1 { status: 1} присвоить online, т.е вместо 1 получить ответ в виде слова online, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала необходимо преобразовать json в ассоциативный массив. Занимается этим функция [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) . Из строки получается массив:

```
$json = '{"status":1}';
$arr = json_decode($json);
```

А потом необходимо изменить статус:

```
$arr['status'] = 'online';
```

И обратно преобразовать в json (функция [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) ) для оправки данных.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, с json decode я знаком, а насчет остального не могу понять, мне нужно изменить ответ 1 на слово online, {status : 1}, а не сам status, скорее всего не правильно задал вопрос

Comment: добавить ещё 1 уровень вложенности? `$arr = ['online' => json_decode($json)]`

Comment: или status заменить на online?  `$arr =  json_decode($json);  $arr2 = ['online' => $arr['status'] ] `

Comment: <?php
$jsonData = file_get_contents ("http://"); 
$json = json_decode($jsonData, true);
echo '';
$output="";
foreach($json['results'] as $results)
{
    $output.="".$results['name']."<br/>";
    $output.="".$results['status']."<br/>";
    $output.="<br/>";
}
echo $output;
?>            вот на примере у меня выводиться ответ на зчение name (разные названия) а на значение status приходит ответ 1 или 2 если ответ 1 это online как вывести слово вместо цифры 1, думаю так я точнее изложил свой вопрос, с этого надо было начинать)

Comment: в цикле где выводится $results['status']  замените на `( $results['status'] == 1 ? 'online' : 'offline' )`

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, помогли